# Will WhatsApp verification delete my contacts & messages?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

I have a WhatsApp account in my old phone, but I have put my SIM card in my new phone. Now when I opened WhatsApp in my old phone its asking for verification. Will verification delete my contacts & messages?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think verification will delete anything, usually it's just an SMS verification code that has to be entered into the app. 2FA ( Two Factor Authentication )

Answer (score -1):

No, it will not delete any of your contacts & messages. It's an simple verification code not more than that.